# Google.Protobuf vs protobuf-net

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

There's already a comparison between protobuf-net and protobuf-csharp-port, but there's also Google's official `Google.Protobuf` nuget package.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each one, which one should I use and in what cases?

Comment: @MarcGravell Is this really a duplicate? The question you marked compares "protobuf-net" with "protobuf-csharp-port", not "Google.Protobuf." I stumbled into this question with the same question as OP.

Comment: @LogicalFallacy protobuf-csharp-port *became* Google.Protobuf; reference: https://github.com/jskeet/protobuf-csharp-port

Comment: @MarcGravell aaah my bad. I've been using Google.Protobuf for a while, and I'm getting really sick of dealing with MSBuild issues for `.proto`->`.cs` generation. Trying to wrap my head around protobuf-net now.

Comment: @LogicalFallacy if you want an easy option: https://protogen.marcgravell.com